# Undefined value after assignment in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to subscribe to a service in angular to get my customer's branding info through their Id.

Firstly, I load all customer data:

```js
this.subscription = this.burstService.getBurst().subscribe(async(response) => {
  if (response) {
    if (response.length > 0) {
      var survey = response[0];
      this.storageService.set("customer", JSON.stringify(survey));
      this.sessionJson.Id = survey.Id;
      this.sessionJson.Name = survey.Name;
      this.sessionJson.Email = survey.Email;
      this.sessionJson.SubDomainName = survey.SubDomainName;
      this.sessionJson.BusinessType = survey.BusinessType;
      this.sessionJson.Address = survey.Address;
      this.sessionJson.Phone = survey.Phone;
      this.sessionJson.Status = survey.Status;
      this.sessionJson.CreatedBy = survey.CreatedBy;
      this.sessionJson.CreationDate = survey.CreationDate;
      this.sessionJson.ModifiedBy = survey.ModifiedBy;
      this.sessionJson.ModificationDate = survey.ModificationDate;
      this.customerId = survey.Id;
    }
  }
});
```

Then I try to subcribe to another api to get their branding data but the customer's Id seems undefined although when I assign its values in the `getBurst` bethod it equals to 1.

```js
this.burstService.getBranding(this.sessionJson.Id!).subscribe(async(response) => {
  if (response) {
    if (response.length > 0) {
      var customerBranding = response[0];
      this.storageService.set("customerBranding", JSON.stringify(customerBranding));
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Error message]

Here are my observables in case its necessary:

```js
getBurst(): Observable < CustomerModel[] > {
  var url = `https://localhost:44397/api/Customer/` + splitUrl[1];
  console.log(url);

  return this.httpClient.get < CustomerModel[] > (url, this.httpOptions);
}

getBranding(id: number): Observable < BrandingModel[] > {
  var url = `https://localhost:44397/api/Branding/` + id
  return this.httpClient.get < BrandingModel[] > (url, this.httpOptions);
}
```

And lastly my class attributes:

```js
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  public survey ? : SurveyModel;

  private subscription: Subscription | undefined;
  private sessionJson: CustomerModel = {};
  private customerId: any;

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService,
    private burstService: BurstService,
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private ip: IpserviceService,
    private router: Router,
    private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.loadData();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: `this.customerId = survey.Id;` <-- you didn't store this in  `this.sessionJson`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @trincot I did, my first assignment inside `getBurst()` suscription after `this.storageService` is `this.sessionJson.Id = survey.Id`

`this.customerId = survey.Id` was just me trying another why to get `survey.Id`, didn't work.

Comment: Better remove that statement from your question, as at least I was confused by it. But with these separated pieces of code it is impossible to verify what `this` is. What did you debug so far?

Comment: I added my class's attributes and constructor method so it's more clear. I'm sorry, english is not my first language

Comment: Also, if I console.log `this.sessionJson` I guet the whole object, but if I try to console.log `this.sessionJson.Id` I guet undefined like ???

Comment: First I see your code `this.burstService.getBranding(this.sessionJson.Id!).` has a exclamation mark in `this.sessionJson.Id!`.

Comment: Then you can try to declare sessionJson like this `sessionJson: CustomerModel = { Id :'', Name: '', ../* other value of your model*/ }` you can't assign value into sessionJson because it don't have any declare value yet

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the properties of the data model `sessionJson` are in `PascalCase` and they should be in `camelCase`. Check
[variable name casing types](https://chaseignited.com/posts/most-common-programming-case-types/) for more info.

For this project, the api is written in ASP.Net Core Web API, which uses C# as the programming language.

It is standard for C# to use `PascalCase` for naming variables, but once the api sends a response to the client, the JSON with the response info has properties in camelCase, which is the standard for JavaScript.

The model is undefined after the assignment because it is looking for a Pascal-cased property in the JSON, which doesn't exist, for example:

`this.sessionJson.Email = survey.Email;`

After storing the response object in survey, all its properties are in camelCase, so in reality if you want to access `survey`'s objet e-mail property you should do:

`this.sessionJson.email = survey.email;`

Notice that I also changes `sessionJson`'s email property. I also suggest naming all your property values in `camelCase` for consistency in JavaScript in this case, since that's the casing type the api is serving.